# Amazon S3 - is it possible to restrict users to scan folders of public folders?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon S3 bucket with several files with randomized file names. The file names are very difficult to guess (for example: `id84hBDs4g0a73nb0Ms9.png`) and I would only want users who know the file name to access them. This means that the Amazon S3 bucket is technically public, but I have to restrict users from "scanning" / "listing" the folder. The user should only be able to access the files they know the file name to and not other files. Is this a possible setting in Amazon S3?

Comment: Why not use s3 presigned urls for that?

Comment: I checked the documentation for predesigned urls, but it seems like the resource is only viewable with during a limited time, I need the access to be persistent. Also can I create them programmatically and have control of the link?

Comment: Yes you can create programmatically but no it is not going to be persistent - otherwise what's the point? Users can share links

Comment: Are you users in cognito? Do you just want the links to be accessible if you have the link or even if multiple people have the link, only 1 specific user can access it?

Comment: It is completely ok that users share links, all assets are still public, we just don't want to make it so easy for them to be shared. But most importantly, make it impossible to discover all objects in a folder in a programmatic or automatic way.

Comment: Users are not in Cognito, in fact, most users are anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to implement [Security through obscurity - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Please note that it is not a form of complete security, as anyone who knows the names of the objects can access them.

You can simply add a **Bucket Policy** that makes all objects in the bucket (or a path within the bucket) 'public'. This policy allows access to the objects, but not listing of the bucket.

From [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html):

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

You will first need to **disable Block Public Access** on the bucket to be able to store this bucket policy.

Comment: I understand, so having `s3:GetObject` action set should be enough to implement security through obscurity? Along turning `Block all public access` off?

Comment: Thanks for the answer John, this is very reassuring for me. As an aside, would you say that filenames that are 108 bits of pure randomness is sufficient enough security through obscurity? And let's say that we have 10^9 files, and we don't want any of them to be found by unauthorized users.

Comment: Some people would argue that Security through Obscurity is not security at all, since once somebody knows a link it can be accessed by anybody. However, if you are happy with that, then a standard [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) would suffice.